# Nautilus script: $NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS empty for WebDAV folders

Tags: webdav, nautilus

When writing a Nautilus script, `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` gives the path to the file whose context menu has been clicked, for instance `/home/nico/test.txt`.

But when the file is within a [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) share, the variable is empty.

Is it a bug?
How to get the path for a WebDAV file?

My script is [intended](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/AlfrescoLinuxMacCheckInOut) to be used for files on WebDAV shares.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just found this list of variables:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto

The one I was looking for is `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS`, it works on WebDAV too, returning for instance `dav://admin@localhost:8080/alfresco/webdav/User%20Homes/leo/test.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Nautilus' `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` is only for LOCAL (mounted) files, and by design is blank for remote files, like `$1`, `$2`...

For REMOTE files, like WebDAV, or Samba network shares, FTP servers, (or any other location where `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_CURRENT_URI` is not like `file://...`), use `$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_URIS`